# Terminal isn't there

Tags: boot, command-line

I just rebooted into Ubuntu and I don't have a terminal icon. My Ubuntu version is 20.04. I rebooted because Mozilla firefox, the in-built browser was not their and after rebooting neither Mozilla Firefox nor terminal was there. Neither Alt + t works nor ctrl + alt + F1. Whenever I use ctrl + alt + F1, it just logs out. Please help!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Any error messages? Why did you reboot was there an issue? You have provided no info that can be used to even begin to help you.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+t invokes the terminal.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+ **F1** is the graphical login screen, so it will always take you to a login form; even if you are logged in. Ctrl+Alt+ **F2** is the graphical session, after logging in (it's the _normal screen_). You can return here any time, if you have logged in before. Ctrl+Alt+ **F3** — **F6** are the virtual consoles.

Comment: An additional way to invoke the terminal is via the activities-overview screen (hit left Windows key), then type terminal, you will see its icon showing up. Once it's open, its icon will show in the dock on the side. Right-click it for a context menu and choose "Add to favourites". That will persist the icon in the dock.

Comment: @Levente I tried doing that but the icon just didn't come